# Problema com Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Estou tentando gerar uma imagem, porém estou recebendo o erro:

```
E: Command line option 'O' [from -O] is not understood in combination
```

Meu Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch

MAINTAINER Fabio J L Ferreira <fabiojaniolima@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
            apt-get install -y apache2 \
            apt-get install -y wget curl unzip apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
            wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
            echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
            apt-get update \
            apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-mcrypt

RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    a2enmod php7.1 \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: A resposta abaixo te ajudou? Tem mais algum problema? Talvez consiga te ajudar

Comment: Ajudou bastante. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre este erro específico, o problema é que você está "misturando" os comandos em uma única linha, o que acaba gerando instruções erradas.

Para separar os comandos você deve usar`&&`, `;` ou `||` - normalmente estes, as vezes é necessário `|` ou `|&`. De forma simplificada:

- `&&` executa o próximo comando apenas se o anterior executou com sucesso;
- `||` executa o próximo comando apenas se o teve falha na execução do anterior;
- `;` sempre executa o próximo comando, independente do resultado do comando anterior - quando `set -e` não estiver sido usado.

O seja, onde está usando isso:

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
    apt-get install -y apache2 \
    apt-get install -y wget curl unzip apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
    wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    apt-get update \
    apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-mcrypt

RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    a2enmod php7.1 \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer
```

Deveria ser algo como isto:

```
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list; \
    apt-get update --fix-missing; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils; \
    apt-get install -y apache2 wget curl unzip apt-transport-https ca-certificates; \
    wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg; \
    apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-mcrypt; \
    a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod php7.1; \
    mkdir -p /var/www && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www; \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Algumas outros pontos de observação:

- o uso de `MAINTAINER` está [obsoleto](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated), prefira usar [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label)
- para evitar a criação de *layers* sem necessidade, aumentando o tamanho da imagem, concentre os comandos numa única instrução - ou em scripts - e remova caches que ferramentas como o *apt* deixam

Uma possível versão final seria a seguinte:

```
FROM debian:stretch

LABEL maintainer "Bruno César <bruno@brunocesar.com>"

RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list; \
    apt-get update --fix-missing; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils; \
    apt-get install -y apache2 wget curl unzip apt-transport-https ca-certificates; \
    wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg; \
    apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-mcrypt; \
    a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod php7.1; \
    mkdir -p /var/www && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www; \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Não testei o uso da imagem, apenas ajustei para "buildar", o repositório *apt* parece estar incorreto, pois não instala algumas dependências.